# Get all the possible combination of a string generated from ASCII character between two numbers

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinations, permutation

I need a simple javascript function which takes 3 inputs

1- Start ASCII value
2- End ASCII value
3- String length

The function will loop from starting value to ending value until length has been made.

For example,

start - 65
end   - 67
length- 2

I want all the combination (length 2) of ASCII of [ 65, 66, 67 ] that is ["A", "B", "C"]

I would like the output as
`AA`
`AB`
`AC`
`BB`
`BA`
`BC`
`CA`
`CB`
`CC`

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: sounds like an interview question :D

Answer (score 3):

To generate all possible combinations, you can use a recursive generator:

```
  function* combine(start, end, depth, previous = []) {
    if(depth <= 0) {
      yield previous;
      return;
    }

    for(let i = start; i <= end; i++)
      yield* combine(start, end, depth - 1, [...previous, i]);
 }
```

Comment: Lovely `yield`. It's always cool to see that someone can actually use these :D

Comment: Thanks :) I really like the simplicity: There is no need to worry about passing the results up to the caller ...

Comment: I am syntax error `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

Comment: The problem with yield is that it still really really slow. few days ago i compared solution with yield and trivial for(let i. and on yields it was 3 times slower on chrome

Comment: @JonasWilms I didn't test it, but I think this will end up in an infinite loop by closely looking at the code. In fact, every recursive combine call will add `65` to the array, ending up in a RangeError. I think a cartesian product here is enough to solve the issue.

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xp3owc9t/ . I'm not that good at generators, but I think this should work.

Comment: @briosheje that is actually a simplified cartesian product. And yes, I missed a `return`...

Comment: @zxxc that statement is as useless as "cars are faster than planes if the plane is driving on a road"

Comment: @JonasWilms wooops, didn't notice that the return was missing :P.